# Next.js api read after '#' in request.url

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, http, next.js

I am trying to read a GET request url that has the query strings after a '#' (out of my control) e.g:

```
http://...onnect/endpoint/#var_name=var_value...
```

request.url does not show anything after `endpoint/`

The problem can be dealt with if the endpoint renders html then i use javascript to get the query string, but that is what I am avoiding - is there a way to get the query string from the request.url or other request.[parameter] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a workaround (avoiding the need to create a Next.js page)

I created a redirect page using `res.writeHead` and `res.write`

```
res.writeHead(302, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
res.write(`
    <script>
        const queryString = window.location.hash.replace('#', '')
        window.location.href='http://...onnect/endpoint?'+ queryString 
    </script>
`)
res.end()
```

Please if you have anything better feel free to answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On the server you will never get the part that starts with #.
But on the client side you can get it with `window.location.hash`.

What you can do if this is in your control, is to extract it from client side then send it to the server in some other way

Comment: I am currently making a workaround using res.writeHead and res.write to create a temporary page that will redirect with the query strings